# Replace a double backslash with a single backslash in a string in python

Tags: python, str-replace, pymysql

I know that variants of this topic have been discussed elsewhere, but none of the other threads were helpful.

I want to hand over a string from python to sql. It might however happen that apostrophes (') occur in the string. I want to escape them with a backslash.

```
sql = "update tf_data set authors=\'"+(', '.join(authors).replace("\'","\\\'"))+"\' where tf_data_id="+str(tf_data_id)+";"
```

However, this will always give `\\'` in my string. Therefore, the backslash itself is escaped and the sql statement doesn't work.

Can someone help me or give me an alternative to the way I am doing this?
Thanks

Comment: provide the raw string you want to be sent to sql

Comment: Have you considered using a prepared statement?

Comment: You could use placeholders and not need any escaping at all. As a bonus you'd not open youself for SQL injection, if and when the escaping overlooks something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply don't.
Also don't concatenate sql queries as these are prone to sql injections.

Instead, use a parameterized query:

```
sql = "update tf_data set authors=%(authors)s where tf_data_id=%(data_id)s"
# or :authors and :data_id, I get confused with all those sql dialects out there


authors = ', '.join(authors)
data_id = str(tf_data_id)

# db or whatever your db instance is called
db.execute(sql, {'authors': authors, 'data_id': data_id})
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very close to what I need. I only get the following error message: ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 66

Comment: @MaxS did you mistype the last `s` in the string? Also remove the `;` entirely as it isn't needed.

Comment: @MaxS Yeah that should work without the ';' in the end. I will delete it from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using double-quoted strings, but still escaping the single quotes within them.  That's not required, all you need to do is escape the backslash that you want to use in the replace operation.

```
>>> my_string = "'Hello there,' I said."
>>> print(my_string)
'Hello there,' I said.
>>> print(my_string.replace("'", "\\'"))
\'Hello there,\' I said.
```

Note that I'm using print.  If you just ask Python to show you its representation of the string after the replace operation, you'll see double backslashes because they need to be escaped.

```
>>> my_string.replace("'", "\\'")
"\\'Hello there,\\' I said."
```

Comment: the problem with the print is that the sql statement won't be printed, therefore sql will see the double backslash as well

Comment: No it won't. The string doesn't contain two backslashes. `'\\'` is a string with exactly one backslash.

Comment: Have you tried before saying what sql will do? :) (oh, Matthias was faster)

Comment: As Matthias has pointed out, you're confusing Python's internal representation of a string containing escaped characters with what the string actually contains.  As @DeepSpace quite rightly posted, manually constructing queries like this is a pretty bad idea regardless.  But it's still important IMHO to understand this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded to, if you are using a python package to execute your SQL use the provided methods with parameter placeholders(if available).

My answer addresses the escaping issues mentioned. 
Use a String literal with prefix r

```
print(r"""the\quick\fox\\\jumped\'""")
```

Output:

```
the\quick\fox\\\jumped\'
```

Comment: if I would print my string it would give my exactly what I wanted it to be. However, I am going to add it to another string and hand it over to sql. printing does not work in this context

Comment: print r"""the\quick\fox\\\jumped\'""" + r"""\addition\\\""""     OUTPUTS: the\quick\fox\\\jumped\'\addition\\\"

Comment: Also you never stated what the "hand it over to sql" part is. Are you using a mysql package? Executing straight on command line? Your exact input and intended output are not made clear in your question making it extremely hard for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: I think that was part of my error: I've tried it with the pymysql satement .execute(sql) and I had errors. Afterwards I was putting the outputs in the console to try the statements without running into python-mysql communication troubles. I probably generated my problem by this way of testing